# Naming of controls

Tags: c#

I have a .ascx control in my project with the name of PM_WorkOrders.ascx. When there's an error, the name is referred to as PM_WorkOrders_ascx. At what point is that control renamed within my project?

Comment: .aspx will be the page (With your user control inside).  .ascx is the control. When it errors it is not renaming, it is stating there is a problem with PM_WorkOrders_ascx (There is a problem with your user control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code behind class of user controls in ASP.NET websites are compiled to MyUserControl_ascx by MSBuild and lives in the namespace ASP.  I think the only way around it is to make your website a Web Application, but not 100% certain on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is the class named generated from the visual studio, you can change it if you want from the code behind and update the control directives to point to the new class name